# Parameter expansion to remove strings with multiple patterns

Tags: bash

I'm building a script that sends the "find" command output to a temp file and from there I use "read" to iterate through all the paths and print two fields into a csv file, one field for the name of the file and the other for the complete path.

```
find -type f \( -iname \*.mp4 -o -iname \*.mkv \) >> $tempfile
while read -r file; do
    printf '%s\n' ${file##*/} ${file} | paste -sd ' ' >> $csvfile
done < $tempfile
rm $tempfile
```

The problem is in the field for the names `${file##*/}`. Some files have spaces in their names and this is causing they not being printed correctly in the csv file, I know I could use this `${file//[[:blank:]]/}` to remove the spaces but I also need to preserve this `${file##*/}` since that parameter expansion allows me to cut all but the name itself of my files (and print those in the first field of the csv file).

I was searching for a way to kinda join the two parameter expansion `${file##*/}` and `${file//[[:blank:]]/}` but I didn't found anything related. Is it possible to solve this using only parameter expansion?, if no what other solutions can fix this? maybe regex?

Edit: Also I will need to add a 3rd field in which the value will depend on a variable.

Comment: `while IFS=$'\n' read -r file; do ...`

Comment: Always-Quote-Your-Variables

Comment: If setting the Internal Field Separator to only split on `'\n'` isn't working, then I would do `find -type f \( -iname \*.mp4 -o -iname \*.mkv \) | awk '{f=$0; sub(/^.*[/]/,"",f); print f","$0}' >> yourfile.csv` which will write `filename,fullpath/filename` to the output fie. You can change the separator to anything you need. If you want a space instead of a comma, change `","` to `" "` (or just remove the quotes an allow the default `OFS` to provide the space, e.g. `print f, $0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GNU `find` (And possibly other implementations?) it can be simplified a lot:

```
find dir/ -type f \( -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.mkv" \) \
          -printf '"%f","'"${newvar//%/%%}"'","%p"\n' > "$csvfile"
```

I put quotes around the fields of the CSV output, to handle cases where the filenames might have commas in them. It'll still have an issue with filenames with doublequotes in the name, though.

---

If using some other version of `find`... well, there's no need for a temporary file. Just pipe the output directly to your while loop:

```
find test1/ -type f \( -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.mkv" \) -print0 |
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
    name=$(basename "$file")
    printf '"%s","%s","%s"\n' "${name//\"/\"\"}" "$newvar" "${file//\"/\"\"}"
done > "$csvfile"
```

This one will escape double quotes appearing in the filename, so if that's the case with your files, prefer it.

Comment: Yep, that works too. Same qualification on the output, if they need a space, simply change the `','` to  space `' '`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OP does say he's using CSV... though his code doesn't seem to be doing so.

Comment: Yep, that is what left me with a question about which way it should go. Using the `find` formatted output will take care of whichever one it happens to be.

Comment: That works nice, but I will need to include a 3rd field which value depends on a variable (I didn't mention it before for simplicity sake), how can I include that? I was trying this `find $cpath -type f \( -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.mkv" \) -printf '"%f" ${newvar} "%p"\n' > csvfile` but that doesn't work.

Comment: @GhostOrder You really should mention stuff like that in your question.

Comment: @Shawn Sorry, I though it wouldn't affect very much the possible solution, I just edited the question.